# Return from PayPal Express to One Page checkout

Tags: checkout, paypal, review, onepage-checkout

Having tried out all the Magento PayPal options, Pro (non-hosted) seems to be the cleanest. While it will incur full-on PCI compliance, it's the neatest approach for CC/DC payments. It all progresses through the OnePage checkout nicely. The Pro Hosted solution with an iframe plonked on the order review step just looks unprofessional.

However, when a payment is made with a PayPal account, instead of coming back to the next OnePage step, it's redirected to the multi-page Magento order review page. Not only is this plain messy and inconsistent, it means any steps after Payment are missed (that can be fixed by rearranging steps)!

I've done a lot of searching and can very few people asking about returning to the OnePage review step after paying with a PayPal account. Surely others want their stores to be consistent when using PayPal!?

I found one article that suggested changing the redirect after returning from PayPal to `/checkout/onepage`, but that just restarts checkout from Step-1! There doesn't seem to be way to tell OnePage which step to continue with?

Has anyone get a solution to allow PayPal checkout with a PP account to come back to the OnePage order review step instead of the multi-page order review?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the magento extension you are using as well as magento version.

Comment: It is expected situation described above. After return from paypal, the only step remains is to confirm payment and place prder. Magento does not divide these steps, It should be one. There is a possibility just remove this page listening responses from paypal and submit it manualy.

Comment: This is standard Magento 1.7.0.2 with the inbuilt PP modules. Turned out that PP Pro was less than ideal too - can't auto return for CC/DC payments and we needed that. So stuck wth PP Hosted. It works ok, but with limited options for customising the experience at PP, it still has a detached feel about it. But that's a PP problem, not Magento!

Comment: Adam, please answer your own question and accept the answer, thanks!#

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer from above so that this can be marked as completed:

PayPal Pro was less than ideal - can't auto return for CC/DC payments

Switched to  PayPal Hosted. It works ok, but with limited options for customising the experience at PP, it still has a detached feel about it. But that's a PP problem, not Magento!